# Cancel a task only if it gets re-run

Tags: unity, async

I have a slow proc gen function that runs when a user changes any parameters.

If a parameter is changed before it has completed, I want it to cancel the task and start a new one.

Currently I have it checking if a cancellation token is null, and if not requesting a cancellation before launching a new task.

```
public static async void Generate(myInputParams Input)
{
    SectorData sectorData;

    if (_tokenSource != null)
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        _tokenSource.Dispose();
    }

    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    myData = await Task.Run(() => SlowFunction(Input, token));

    // do stuff with new data
}
```

This does work but it seems to me that it's possible for the new task to be run before the cleanup code and cancelation in the previous one have completed.

Is there a way I can guarantee the previous task is done before starting the new one?

Comment: `it seems to me that it's possible for the new task to be run before the cleanup code and cancelation in the previous one have completed` How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: Well, my understanding is that the threaded function polls the token and if it finds the cancel flag, arbitrary code is run which ultimately results in the function exiting but there's no guarantee it's instant, and it's in concurrent thread. Meanwhile, Generate() does not particularly care how long that other thread will take to exit and goes straight to the next block and launches a new task. Is that wrong?

Comment: How about using a simple bool flag to record whether there is an ongoing task?

Comment: @arcadeperfect But you control the other task also, no? Or is it third-party? If it is third-party you can always wrap it in your own task.